# How do I solve NoneType object is not callable with BeautifulSoup and Bottle?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, bottle, python-3.4

I have this code inside one of my routes in a small Bottle project:

```
@route('/method/')
def method():
    import urllib.request
    from bottle import response
    response.content_type = 'text/xml'

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    r=opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
    content = str(r.read())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    return soup.title
```

I have read similar questions. I've tried everything, but I'm always getting the same error. I don't even know if it's related with bottle.

I have used virtualenv to create an isolated environment with Python3. The version of BeautifulSoup is 4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I'm always getting the same, giant stacktraces of:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55533)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 305, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55536)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 305, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2015 14:50:42] "GET /extract_web_information/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55539)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 321, in close
    self.result.close()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 305, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

**How I'm running the server**

```
source bin/activate
python myserver.py

After that, GET request from a browser
```

I have tested that the request is correctly made.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: where are data and filelike methods in you your code snippet ?

Comment: The trace is not from within the `method` code. You're showing us the wrong code.

Comment: Sorry, I've added everything I see in the terminal. I don't see what is going on, and I don't see anything that points me to the problem...

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I've added how I'm running the code. Thanks also @Anmol_uppal for your comment. I don't know what data and filelike are. It seems to be code from Bottle or WSGI server.

Comment: show us the extraction script

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is no `<title>`.  To illustrate this, try replacing your code

```
return soup.title
```

with:

```
return soup.title or "no title found."
```